# Mysql fetch array error 2

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, fetch

I have this code:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$d = date('Y-m-d');
$m = date("m");
$day = date("d");
$t = date("His");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$c = file_get_contents('http://api.wipmania.com/'.$ip);

echo "<h2>ALL RESULTS TODAY:</h2><table>";
$_GET['c'] = $c;
$sc = $_GET['sc'];
if($c === "key"){
    if($sc === "t"){
        $result = "SELECT * FROM main WHERE date = '$d' ORDER BY time";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {echo "<tr><td>".$row['key'] . "</td><td> " . $row['country']."</td><td>".$row['ip']."</td></tr>";  }
        }

}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

i have tried without `$con`: `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`, but it was the same...

But nothings appear...
no error no results...
Please help... Thanks!

Comment: You need to run your query - `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($con))`, where $sql is the query you want to run, and $con is a valid mysqli database connection.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot `mysqli_query`.

replace this

```
   $result = "SELECT * FROM main WHERE date = '$d' ORDER BY time";
```

by

```
   $result =mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM main WHERE date = '$d' ORDER BY time");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not connected to the database or queried your results:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname) or die(mysqli_error());
//...
$your_query = "SELECT * FROM main WHERE date = '$d' ORDER BY time";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $your_query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to perform the query.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM main WHERE date = '$d' ORDER BY time");
```